# Toggle off image

Tags: javascript, image, toggle

I have this code and would like to remove the selection (text box) when the image is deselected (on toggle). Also, is it possible to make the text box hidden so when it's passed on a "submit" I can get only the selected images?

What's the best approach?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div img {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

img {
  padding: 5px;
}
img.clicked {
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function setFormImage(id) {
    if (id != '' && !document.getElementById('input_'+id)) {
        var img = document.createElement('input');
        img.type = 'text';
        img.id = 'input_'+id;
        img.name = 'images[]';
        img.value = id;

        document.imageSubmit.appendChild(img);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqueryimages img').click(function(){
        setFormImage(this.id);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre>


</pre>
<div id="jqueryimages" style="float: left; width: 49%;">
    <h1>Image Selection</h1>
    5. <img src="http://www.handmadepotery.com/home.gif" id="img-5"/>
    <br/>
    6. <img src="http://www.handmadepotery.com/home.gif" id="img-6"/>
    <br/>
    7. <img src="http://www.handmadepotery.com/home.gif" id="img-7"/>
    <br/>
    8. <img src="http://www.handmadepotery.com/home.gif" id="img-8"/>
</div>
<script>
ims = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for( i=0 ; i<ims.length ; i++ ){
  ims[i].onclick=function() {
    if (this.className == "clicked") {
      this.className = "";
    } else {
      this.className = "clicked";
    }
  };
}
</script>

<h1>Form Submit</h1>
<form name="imageSubmit" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="View Selected"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an FYI... jQuery 1.4.4 is very outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Added an else if to your setFormImage function:

```
function setFormImage(id) {
 var imgTxt = document.getElementById('input_'+id);
 if (id != '' && !imgTxt) {
    var img = document.createElement('input');
    img.type = 'text';
    img.id = 'input_'+id;
    img.name = 'images[]';
    img.value = id;

    document.imageSubmit.appendChild(img);
 }else if(imgTxt){
    document.imageSubmit.removeChild(imgTxt);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a "cleanup" suggestion, you can eliminate all of this:

```
ims = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for( i=0 ; i<ims.length ; i++ ){
  ims[i].onclick=function() {
    if (this.className == "clicked") {
      this.className = "";
    } else {
      this.className = "clicked";
    }
  };
}
```

with this:

```
$("img").toggle(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
});
```

placed **here**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqueryimages img').click(function(){
        setFormImage(this.id);
    });
// PUT HERE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a more backbone-ish approach and just re-render the form or the part of the form you're interested in. Also, if you're gonna use jquery, you might as well use it to help you generate the changes to the form:

http://jsfiddle.net/a9qdr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allImages = $("#jqueryimages img");
    var theForm = $("form[name=imageSubmit]");

    var renderImageInputs = function(){

        // empty the form
        theForm.find("[name^=images]").remove();

        // fill it back up
        allImages.filter(".clicked").each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $("<input>", {
                type: 'text',
                id: 'input_' + id,
                name: 'images[]',
                value: id
            }).appendTo(theForm);
        });
    };

    // bind to clicks on the images    
    allImages.click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
        renderImageInputs();
    });
});
```